# Calling a method on a hooked function agrument

Tags: c++, frida

I hooked a function with Frida that looks like this:

```
int compute(int size, Event* event);
```

There is a method on the Event class (the toString() method) that i want to call, but not finding a way to do so (Using the Javascript API).

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: `event->toString();` ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe the way i worded it wasn't clear. I am intercepting the function using the Frida Javascript API (using Interceptor.attach). and i want to call the method from inside that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? When posting a question about Frida code you should post the hooking code you currently have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.